# Area under the curve of P.D.F function for continuous data

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

When we take discrete random variable (X) of a specific range "R" into consideration, given that f(x) = y is the P.D.F, the summation of all the probability values available equals 1. expressed in:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i) =1$$

So we added y values together only here. However when we have a continuous random variable (X), and we want to express that the sum of all f(x) values is 1:
$$\int_{Rx}^{} f(x) dx =1$$

Now from my understanding of integration, that the integral of a function is the summation of areas of height equal to $f(x)$ and a width that's infinitely small $dx$ in a given interval, I thought that $\int_{Rx}^{} f(x) dx$ is equivalent to the $E(x)$ (expected value) of random variable X, since we express that in discrete R.V as: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} xf(x_i)$$, this gave me an intuition of "summation of areas" ,so $x$ would turn in continuous R.V to $dx$, but E(x) in continuous R.V happens to be 
$$\int_{Rx}^{} xf(x) dx $$

While my book mentions that $f(x)$ is given as P.D.F for continuous data, I don't really get why it states $P(X=c) = \int_{c}^{c} f(x) dx = 0$ rather than saying that $P(X=c) = f(c)$

Could someone either correct my understanding of integration, or explain why these properties of continuous P.D.F are like this? Not to mention that discrete r.v probability is expressed at certain value as $P(X=c) = f(c)$

Comment: $\int_{c}^{c} f(x) dx=F(c)-F(c)=0$, where $F(x)$ denotes the cdf.

Comment: PDF is "probability density function" and is only for integration.  It is not the same as a PMF ("probability mass function") such as when $X$ takes a finite number of possible values $\{x_1, ..., x_n\}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n P[X=x_i]=1$. Note of course that a PDF value $f_X(x)$ is not a probability, and it may be larger than 1 at certain values of $x$.  You should never write things like $\sum_i f(x)_i$ or $\sum_i i f(x)_i$ since nobody knows what that means [What do you mean by $f(x)_i$?] and at best, it looks like you are incorrectly treating a PDF as a probability.

Comment: As a practice problem that will give you intuition, can you state the PDF $f_X(x)$ for the case when $X$ is uniformly distributed over the interval $\left[0,\frac{1}{10}\right]$?

Comment: @callculus yes, but it doesn't make sense that the probability of all $X=x_i$ (a certain point) is equal to zero..

Micheal sorry fixed. do you mean that PMF is for discrete data and PDF is for continuous data? And how so PDF function doesn't give out the probability of a certain X? what does it represent then?

Comment: Can you give an answer for my second comment?  Uniform PDF over the interval $[0, 1/10]$?

Comment: Intuitive: You have infinitely many $x$ values. What is the probability that you hit a specific value?

Comment: @passepartout zero probability events can happen.

Comment: @Michael, not really, since i'm now confused about what does it really mean..
,callculus Hmm that makes sense now, so we're supposed to take probabilities through a give interval,
kludg yeah ofc, but i thought here (from my understanding of pdf) that integration doesn't really give us the real probability of a single x

Comment: @passepartout : I observe that you cannot answer my question about the uniform PDF.  In that case, you must admit that you do not know what a PDF is, so, any further questions are useless until you get that definition.  A PDF for a continuous random variable $X$ is a nonnegative function such that integrating over an interval gives you the probability that $X$ is in that interval. For my question, it must of course be a nonnegative function $f_X(x)$ that satisfies $\int_0^{1/10} f_X(x)dx = 1$ (since $P[X \in [0, 1/10]]=1$). Can you guess what $f_X(x)$ might be for $X$ uniform over $[0,1/10]$?

Comment: I suppose a more structured question is: Let $X$ be uniformly distributed over $[0,1/10]$.  The PDF has the form $$f_X(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
a &\mbox{ if $x \in [0,1/10]$} \\
b  & \mbox{ otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right.$$  Can you find the values of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. @Michael I really have no clue about the concept of PDF you are referring to right now, all my tutor taught me about it is that it outputs the probability of a certain x, nothing more than it's range is [0,1] of all available p(x) values is 1.

Comment: You have everything you need in the above two comments, how can you say you have "no clue"?   It must integrate to 1. **That is a huge clue**.  It has the form of the above with only $a$ and $b$ left to solve for.  **That is another big clue.**   With these two clues, you can determine the (only) value of $a$ that could possibly work.

Comment: I assume a = 10, b = 0?

Comment: Yes, so you see that $f_X(x)=10$ for all $x \in [0, 1/10]$, highlighting that the density is not the same as a probability (it can be larger than 1). Nevertheless you can integrate over any interval you want to get the probability that $X$ is in that interval, for example $$P[X \in [0, 1/20]] = ??, P[X \in [1/20, 50]]=??, P[X \in [1/20,1/20 +  \delta]]=??$$

Comment: I see. so now PMF is what gives us the probability and the integration of PDF gives us the probability as well. But what does PDF (the value of a pdf value at certain x) give us then?